# Outlook for Mac add-in with the newly released office.js API

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin, office-js

We have an add-in for Office Apps - using the compose form on Outlook appointments in the calendar.

Because finally the office.js add-ins support for Outlook for Mac is out as written [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/outlookformac/2016/12/07/add-ins-for-outlook-2016-for-mac-now-in-insider-fast/), I have some questions:

- How can I debug the JS in the add-in side pane in Outlook for Mac? Since the behavior is sometimes different to Outlook Web
- `Office.context.mailbox.item.body.setAsync(newBody, { coercionType: Office.CoercionType.Html }, callback)` seems to do nothing, only for `Office.CoercionType.Text` it seems to work
- Is it possible to open a web page in the browser instead of a modal window? Because `window.open(url, target, features)` opens a modal window on top of the appointment, which is again different behavior to Outlook Web Client
- It looks like JS is much slower in Outlook for Mac

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question #1 
MacOutlook uses webkit to render addin page. You can run the following command from CLI

defaults write NSGlobalDomain WebKitDeveloperExtras -bool true

Restart the outlook and invoke the Add-in. You will see new menu item inspect Element which will let you inspect the elements in the page.

Question #3:  If the URL to be opened in a domain that is not listed in appmanifest, the URL will be opened in a separate browser window. The url to be opened is in the domain listed in appmainfest, you will see a popup window. MacOutlook uses modal window due to the limitations of webkit library currently being used.

Question #2 : Can you give specific steps to reproduce the problem and share the Outlook version that you are using - We do not see this problem

Senthil @ Microsoft

Comment: It's version 15.30, calling `Office.context.mailbox.item.body.setAsync(newBody, { coercionType: Office.CoercionType.Html }, callback)` sets the body to an empty string, not the `newBody` value. It works just work text, same code for Html works on Outlook Web and Outlook Windows

Comment: About #3, it works that way indeed, unfortunately I can't remove the url from the manifest, because then our OAuth is opening in the browser and can't "give back" the token to the side panel js. Would be good to have a choice, since clicked links open in the browser even if the url is in the manifest.

Comment: do you know a similar command like in Question #1 but for Outlook for Windows desktop? I know it's IE11 inside, but I can't inspect any element or debug JS when it's inside Outlook 2013?

Comment: @alekkowalczyk for Windows use `C:\Windows\System32\F12\F12Chooser.exe` (sometimes at `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\F12\F12Chooser.exe`) which opens a dialog part of IE Dev Tools and you can choose which IE instance to attach the Dev Tools to. Among the choices you should see Outlooks IE instance.