# How to Debug Microsoft Outlook for Mac (or Windows) Web Add-In?

Tags: macos, outlook, outlook-web-addins, vscode-debugger

The problem:
I have a feature for a Microsoft Outlook web add-in which works fine in [Office 365 Outlook](https://outlook.office.com), but when I test the same feature on Outlook for Mac or Outlook for Windows, the same feature doesn't work. The web add-in still installs fine on Outlook for Mac, it's just that there is a discrepancy between the behavior I am seeing on Office 365 Outlook and Outlook for Mac (this is also true when testing on Outlook for Windows, which has the same behavior as the Mac version).

What I've tried (Mac): I've tried running `defaults write NSGlobalDomain WebKitDeveloperExtras -bool true` as suggested from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41109115/outlook-for-mac-add-in-with-the-newly-released-office-js-api?rq=1) and `defaults write com.microsoft.Outlook OfficeWebAddinDeveloperExtras -bool true` as suggested [here](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs-pr/blob/master/docs/testing/debug-office-add-ins-on-ipad-and-mac.md#debugging-with-safari-web-inspector-on-a-mac) and have an option to View Source which opens the HTML source in what appears to be a TextEdit window, but I'm still unable to inspect element in order to see any errors.

What I've tried (Windows):
I've tried using the [VSCode Debugger Extension for Office Add-Ins](https://github.com/OfficeDev/vscode-debugger-extension-for-office-addins/issues/18) to try to attach the debugger to Outlook for Windows, but keep running into this ['Error processing attach'](https://github.com/OfficeDev/vscode-debugger-extension-for-office-addins/issues/18) error.

Additional Notes:
On Mac, I'm running Microsoft Outlook for Mac version 16.43 on MacOS Catalina version 10.15.6 and on Windows I'm running Outlook on Windows 10 Pro version 1909 inside a VM.

My understanding is that while debugging web add-ins for Word, Excel, and PowerPoint are all pretty well supported, debugging add-ins for Outlook on Mac or Windows is somewhat limited at the moment. Has anyone had success in debugging Outlook web add-ins running on Outlook for Mac and/or Windows?

Comment: "HTML source in an .rtf file" - there's so much wrong with that

Comment: Note that an "Add-in" for desktop Office programs is very different from a "Web Add-In" - they're very different technologies (one is a Win32-only COM API, the other is JavaScript).

Answer (score 0):

For Outlook for Mac, we think this is specific to the Mac App Store build of Office, which currently doesn't support those flags. To workaround this, you will need to get a non App Store build. You can get one by signing up for the developer program and getting a tenant: https://aka.ms/o365devprogram. (similar issue: https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/506)

For Outlook for Windows, we suggest attaching a debugger. Instructions for how to attach a debugger can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/debug-add-ins-using-f12-developer-tools-on-windows-10). Note that there is a different debugger for add-ins that run in Edge and IE.

Comment: I downloaded a non App Store build and am running into the same issues unfortunately, see my [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Office-Addin-Scripts/issues/667#steps-to-reproduce). **NB**: the safari web inspector also [didn't work](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/968905/how-can-i-use-the-safari-web-inspector-on-outlook.html) for me